# How to calculate the value of an input that has a spinner so when the number changes, the result changes too?

Tags: javascript, forms, spinner, calculation

I'm very new to Javascript and I need some help in a basic function that could calculate the value of an input that has a spinner and display the result in a second field.

My HTML :

```
<form action="simulation_investment">

Nombre de vache(s):<br>

<input type="number" id= "cowsnumber" min="1" max="999"  onblur="calculate()"> 
<br>

Coût estimé du bétail:<br>
 <input type="numbers" id="cost">
 <br><br>
 </form>
```

My Javascript :

```
calculate = function() {
    var cowsnumber = document.getElementById('cowsnumber').value;
    document.getElementById('cost').value = parseInt(cowsnumber) * 1500;
}
```

I'm actually trying to make it work on JSFiddle but I get no result, nothing happens to the second input when I change the value of the first which has the spinner.

Thank you in advance ! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = document.getElementById('cowsnumber');
a.addEventListener("blur", function(){
document.getElementById('cost').value = parseInt(a.value) * 1500
})
```

```html
<form action="simulation_investment">

Nombre de vache(s):<br>

<input type="number" id= "cowsnumber" min="1" max="999" > 
<br>

Coût estimé du bétail:<br>
 <input type="numbers" id="cost">
 <br><br>
 </form>
```